# Ubuntu Server and lack of default (text) web browser with Barracuda Web Login

Tags: server, internet, browser, default-browser

Where I work we have a Barracuda web login that I log into my company internet via an intranet web browser.

As Ubuntu Server (16.04) does not appear to have a browser I cannot use apt-get.

Apparently US used to come with w3m as a default browser (which would be nice) however at the moment I cannot get anywhere.

Comment: you shouldn't need a web browser to use apt/apt-get.... you are connected to server command line via ssh or terminal? can you run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade?

Comment: I need a web browser to log into the internet from our network.

Comment: can you download the deb of your desired browser on a different computer and put it on a usb drive and sneaker net it to your server? you can download the proper deb here and install it using dpkg from command line: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/w3m/w3m_0.5.3-26build1_amd64.deb

Comment: Looks like the only possible solution however I already tried that with lynx and links and it said I needed other libraries too. :sigh: I guess this is the only way to go. This should be fun!!! I am sure I will get all the packages eventually!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this package first

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/16.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/libgc1c2_7.4.2-7.3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb.html

and w3m will install afterwards.

*update - This did not work but lynx did.

Installed this first

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lynx-common

Then Lynx itself

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/lynx/download

And I got to my company login page.

Practically flying along now getting stuff done.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the internet from a different machine, you can download the deb file to a usb stick and manually install it on your server. If you are using 64 bit, do the following (if 32 bit replace the 64 in the link with 32 and follow same directions)

[Download the .deb file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/w3m/w3m_0.5.3-26ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb) and copy it to a thumb drive. Mount the thumb drive on your server and navigate to it (eg cd /media/user/drive ). Now you can manually install the browser like this:

```
dpkg --install w3m_0.5.3-26ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```